# Problems with updating c# variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, highcharts

I am learning to work with javascript and c#. So, I was using highcharts to plot some data that I pass from my c# to javascript. Now, I wanted to manually update the variables in c# to see the change in the values in the javascript but for some reason, the variables do not update. What could I be doing wrong? This is what I tried so far. I updated the variable "merchantname" but for some reason nothing happens in my front end.

Comment: mmm i don't suggest you to work with C# and js in that way (mix back end code and front end) .. but first of all .. i see a strage thing in your code ... how you call the setInterval(Counter, 60000); ..i think you have to call it with () like: setInterval(Counter(), 60000);

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi `setInterval` needs a function to call. passing `Counter` is correct, because that is a reference to the function. `Counter()` would be the result of invoking the function, which in this case would be `undefined` since it does not return anything.

Comment: the serializer will only be called the first time you are rendering the page, not on subsequent calls from your ajax request, you will have to send the data from C# through a response, parse that data in javascript and then call the klm / abc function with the parsed data

Comment: @Icepickle:- Can you kindly help me out with a rough pseudo code if possible ? I am still new to javascript, so things are a bit off my head..

Comment: @jessica Sure, I can look a bit in it, do you have a certain technology stack in mind, or do you wish to keep the asmx approach? I created a bit of an example which I can add, however it would be good to know if you will keep your current setup, or if you wish to use a more modern version of webservices?

Comment: @Icepickle:- I have to use my current approach as my supervisor doesnt want me to use any other way. So, I am stuck up with this approach. If there is way I can solve the problem of updating the variables and passing it to javascript function because once I connect the program to my server, the server will be updating the variables with new data and which has to be sent to the javascript function.

Comment: @Icepickle:- Once again thank you for helping me out.

Comment: @jessica no problem, just to make sure, the asmx stays, however, how you load/manipulate your data can be changed, and your javascript can be altered as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132013/discussion-between-icepickle-and-jessica).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your page is not updating the way you think it should update, is a bit twofold:

- Though you use ajax to send requests to your webservice, your real data service endpoint has a void return, meaning it doesn't return anything, this is not very practical
- Your counter service is doing some updates, and returns a number, but that's it

So on the C# side, you should rather return a typed object, so that you can use it inside your javascript response, let's say, you add a class called FruitItem

```
public class FruitItem {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Failed { get; set; }
    public int Succeeded { get; set; }
    public int Service { get; set; }

    public FruitItem(string name, int failed, int succeeded, int service) {
        Name = name;
        Failed = failed;
        Succeeded = succeeded;
        Service = service;
    }
}
```

Like this, you can keep your data more cohesive than through the use of disconnected array's.

This data now has to be transferred back to your client, so in your current setup, we need to change the `calctransctl` method so that it returns this kind of data. If we change it in the following way, we can return an array of FruitItems

```
[WebMethod]
public static FruitItem[] calctranscs()
{
    return new FruitItem[] {
        new FruitItem("Strawberry", 100, 200, 400),
        new FruitItem("Apples", 200, 100, 400),
        new FruitItem("Pineapple", 300, 200, 400),
        new FruitItem("Mango", 100, 200, 400)
    };
}
```

Alternatively (in case you wish to keep using the disconnected arrays), you could also return an anonymous object containing the disconnected arrays, like so:

```
[WebMethod]
public static object calctranscs() {
    return new { 
        merchant_names = new string[] { "Strawberry", "Apples", "Pineapple", "Mango" },
        failures = new int[] {100, 200, 300, 100},
        succeeded = new int[] {200, 100, 200, 200},
        service = new int[] {400, 400, 400, 400}
    };
}
```

This would return an anonymous object containing your data (for the time being, the rest of the answer will rather contain the version with the objects)

Next thing we have to change, is handling the now received data in your ajax callback, your calcfunc method must now handle the response it gets

```
function callfunc() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getcharts.aspx/calctranscs",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            klm( result.d );
            abc( result.d );
            // please note, I removed the setInterval here, we can do it at initializing time
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert(result.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

We now know that your result.d contains an array of objects, containing the following properties

- `Name`: `string`
- `Failed`: `number`
- `Succeeded`: `number`
- `Service`: `number`

So, to map these to your expected input for your chart functions, you can change the klm function like so (and abc function in a similar way as well)

```
function mapData( data, property ) {
  return data.map( function( item ) {
    return item[property];
  } );
}

function klm( data ) {
    var merchantname = mapData( data, "Name" );
    var servicevalue = mapData( data, "Service" );
    var failedvalue = mapData( data, "Failed" );
    var successvalue = mapData( data, "Succeeded" );
    // the rest of your code is unchanged
}
```

This function will receive your data, and then create the arrays based on the properties, in case you would give your anonymous object back containing the arrays, you would have it a bit easier like for example

```
function klm( data ) {
    var merchantname = data.merchant_names;
    var servicevalue = data.service;
    var failedvalue = data.failures;
    var successvalue = data.succeeded;
    // the rest of your code is unchanged
}
```

An extra change I made in your .aspx page was to only load the full data, once all the javascript files were loaded, so this will wrap your entire javascript part

```
$(function() {
    function callfunc() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getcharts.aspx/calctranscs",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                klm( result.d );
                abc( result.d );
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert(result.responseText);
            }
        });
    }

    function Counter() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getcharts.aspx/Counter",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result.d);
                callfunc();
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert(result.responseText);
            }
        });

    }

    function mapData( data, property ) {
        return data.map( function( item ) {
            return item[property];
        } );
    }

    function klm( data ) {
        var merchantname = mapData( data, "Name" );
        var servicevalue = mapData( data, "Service" );
        var failedvalue = mapData( data, "Failed" );
        var successvalue = mapData( data, "Succeeded" );

        Highcharts.chart('container1', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Stacked column chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: merchantname
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Transaction Status'
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -30,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 25,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
                borderColor: '#CCC',
                borderWidth: 1,
                shadow: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Service',
                data: servicevalue
            }, {
                name: 'Failure',
                data: failedvalue
            }, {
                name: 'Success',
                data: successvalue
            }]
        });

    }

    function abc( data ) {
        var merchantname = mapData( data, "Name" );
        var servicevalue = mapData( data, "Service" );
        var failedvalue = mapData( data, "Failed" );
        var successvalue = mapData( data, "Succeeded" );

        Highcharts.chart('container3', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Stacked column chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                //  categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
                categories: merchantname
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total fruit consumption'
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -30,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 25,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
                borderColor: '#CCC',
                borderWidth: 1,
                shadow: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Service',
                data: servicevalue
            }, {
                name: 'Failure',
                data: failedvalue
            }, {
                name: 'Success',
                data: successvalue
            }]
        });
    }

    callfunc();
    setInterval(Counter, 30000);
});
```

The notable changes is the wrapping `$(function() { /*... your code ...*/ })` that will wait until all javascript code is loaded, and that the setInterval got moved from the callback to one of the first functions being called (after callfunc).

Each time the interval is triggered, and it succeeds, it will trigger a new call to callfunc, and your data will potentially be redrawn

(note that the last code is also the working code using the FruitItem text, not the anonymous object)